# Sharing data within threads using a common COM dll

Tags: c++, com

i am fairly new to COM, hence would appreciate any help i can get:

i have two threads A and B. thread A calls a COM dll to do some processing and at the end the dll stores the result in a hash map and writes it to a file. i need to know how i can send this hash map to thread B. As far as i understand COM udt do not support hash maps. the hash map can in some scenarios store up to 20000 values, hence i am looking for a solution that will not impact performance.

the main program is written in c++.

Comment: It's not clear what COM has to do with it. It sounds like COM is used to generate the hash map and that's it. Is that correct? Regardless. If the two threads are in the same module (exe or dll, and they better be or you're opening a completely different can of worms), you should be able to use conventional inter-thread mechanisms to pass the hash map around. A little more detail will help: can you clarify the pieces? Is this an EXE or a DLL? Who owns the threads?

Answer (score 0):

Since COM dll creates file, you can return simply file name or in a more complex scenario - opened file handle

Comment: thanks for the answering jacob. from a performance perspective, again parsing the file would be too slow for me.